# NaCL flag is not enabled after loading chrome extension from Web Store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient

I have chrome extension (not a chrome app) that use on some site in iframe:

```
<iframe id="application" src="chrome-extension://<extension_id>/index.html"></iframe>
```

This extension adds Native Client object to the page by the following way:

```
<embed name="nacl_module" id="nacl_module" src="/naclmodule.nmf" type="application/x-nacl">
```

After uploading extension to the Web Store, it starts generate the following error message in the console: **"Only unpacked extensions and apps installed from the Chrome Web Store can load NaCl modules without enabling Native Client in about:flags."**

When I upload this extension to the browser as unpackaged (upload from local folder), the error was not occured.

I can check enabling of Native Client flag in Chrome settings and ask user enable it manualy. But it isn't the best way.

***Maybe I do something wrong and for extensions that was installed from Web Store should enable NaCL flag automaticaly as well?***

The manifect.json file of extension is:

```
{
   "description": "<description>",
   "homepage_url": "<site_url>",
   "icons": {
      "128": "icon128.PNG"
   },
   "key": <key>,
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "minimum_chrome_version": "28",
   "name": "<name>",
   "offline_enabled": true,
   "permissions": [  "alarms", "storage", "unlimitedStorage" ],
   "platforms": [ {
      "nacl_arch": "x86-64",
      "sub_package_path": "_platform_specific/x86_64"
   }, {
      "nacl_arch": "x86-32",
      "sub_package_path": "_platform_specific/x86_32"
   } ],
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "0.30",
   "web_accessible_resources": [ "/*" ]
}
```

**Update:**
I set sorce url for iframe in js code. So I tried to use chrome.extension.getURL by following way:

```
var frame = document.getElementById("frame_app");
frame.src = chrome.extension.getURL('index.html');
```

But get en error in runtime: *"Cannot read property 'getURL' of undefined"*

Then I foun information about [content_script in chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) . So I have added to the manifest file the following:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*.mysite.com/*", "https://*.mysite.com/*"],
    "js": ["contentscript.js"]
}],
```

You can find contentscript.js file below:

```
console.log("CONTENT SCRIPT - test")
window.postMessage({ type: "FROM_SCRIPT", text: chrome.extension.getURL('index.html') }, "*")
```

And handled this message in js file:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  // We only accept messages from ourselves
  if (event.source != window)
    return;

  if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_SCRIPT")) {
   var frame = document.getElementById("frame_app");
     frame.src = "";        
        frame.src = event.data.text;
  }
}, false);
```

It works when I upload this extension to the chrome from local folder (unpackged extension). But after uploading and installing from Web Store still get en error: *"Only unpacked extensions and apps installed from the Chrome Web Store can load NaCl modules without enabling Native Client in about:flags."*

Comment: The way that error is worded suggests only webstore apps are supported, but [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/renderer/chrome_content_renderer_client.cc?sq=package:chromium&dr=C&rcl=1473347893&l=961) says webstore extensions are also supported (that is inside your iframe it should work). So my guess is that you've hardcoded wrong `extension_id` in the iframe url instead of using [chrome.extension.getURL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL)

Comment: I set scr for iframe in js code. So earlier it was:`frame.src = 'chrome-extension://<extension_id>/index.html'`. Changed url on `chrome.extensions.getURL('index.html')` - get en error because chrome.extensions = undefined. Then read about [contentscript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication). Added to manifest `"content_scripts": [{"matches": [<all urls>],"js": ["contentscript.js"]}],`. In the contentscript.js get url and postmessage with this url to website page. But still get an error with NaCL flag. Maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: initially my frame has empty src (src=''), and at the first time I set it after getting extension ID

Comment: I noticed that it works if I open url _"chrome-extension://<extension_id>/index.html"_ in new tab. But it does not work inside frame.